# C# Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core reference

Tags: c#, cryptography

I am fairly new to c#, however I am building a console application that accesses the Marvel API, and I need to generate a MD5 hash for the API call. After researching a lot I have found that you can use the System.Security.Cryptography namespace or the Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core namespace to generate the hash. I am currently attempting to use the System.Security.Cryptography namespace like so:

```
 public string Hash(string data)
    {
        MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
        byte[] toBeHashedBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(toBeHashedBytes);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(hash[i].ToString());
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

The hash generated from this method is not valid when being passed to the marvel API however. I am attempting to use the Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core namespace but I cannot seem to find what reference is needed. Do I just need to add a reference or do I need to download an assembly first?

I am using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic issue is that you are combining bytes in base 10 rather than hexadecimal. Fix the append line like so:

```
sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("x2"));
```

The method then gives the correct value for the input "1abcd1234" of

> ffd275c5130566a2916217b101f26150

as described in their [documentation](https://developer.marvel.com/documentation/authorization).

Comment: Thank you! I knew It was something super simple. I definitely need to learn more on how hashing works.

Comment: Presumably you want "x2", so a leading 0 is written when needed.  (Also "x2" instead of "X2" eliminates the redundant ToLower)

Answer (score 0):

Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core is a namespace for UWP or Windows App, it's not for Console Application. You cannot use it in Console Application.